# Text is not displayed in shiny dashboard header after combining with library bs4Dash

Tags: r, shinydashboard, bs4dash

Im trying to include some text inside shiny dashboard header. While this works when I combine it with library `bs4Dash` the text is not displayed any more.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bs4Dash)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "demo"
  ), 
  dashboardSidebar(), 
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(
      '.myClass { 
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        padding: 0 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: black;
      }
    '))),
    tags$script(HTML('
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("header").find("nav").append(\'<span class="myClass"> Text Here </span>\');
      })
     '))
  )
) 
server <- function(input, output) { } 
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Different DOM structure for both scenarios

The reason is that the `dashboardHeader` has different tags structure when you are using only `shinydashboard` and when you add additional `bs4Dash`.
Be careful with it as it can exposed a lot of different problems like `dropdownMenu` inside `dashboardHeader` can look very bad for such packages combo.

First case:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
# jquery
# $("header").find("nav").append(\'<span class="myClass"> Text Here </span>\');
```

Second case, I do not feel this selector is elegant. The best will be to have custom `tags$div(id = "xyz")` and inject text to it, but this is not so obvious when using dashboards. Sum up it works.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(bs4Dash)
# jquery
# $("body > div.wrapper > nav > ul:nth-child(1)").append(\'<span class="myClass"> Text Here </span>\');
```